# Fullcalendar Angular: Add an Event based on Day of the Week.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

Being quite new to fullcalendar. I have my event that creates a new event for me based on Start Date and End Date.

I want to create an event based on day of the week. So e.g event 1 shud be on Monday and event 2 should be on Tuesday.

Is it possible to be done in FullCalendar Angular.

So for example how do i add this event to Monday

```
{
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
        allDay: false}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: could you upload some code with plunkr/jsfiddle

Comment: to which Monday? Last Monday? Next Monday?

Answer (score 1):

**Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) for convenience** (comes with fullcalendar)

**Example:** Event on next monday

```
{
    title: 'Birthday Party',
    start: moment().day(1).hours(19).minutes(0).format(),
    end: moment().day(1).hours(22).minutes(30).format(),
    allDay: false
}
```

**Note:** Usually, moment.js comes in handy for several other date related tasks, too: converting timezones, getting timestamps, localized formatting, etc.

Comment: You just saved my life. Thank you sir !!